# Find the closest (in manhattan distance) pair of points in a sparse matrix

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I am solving an algorithm problem.
I have a matrix M, which contains 0, 1 and 2. It is a sparse matrix.
The problem is to use the quickest way to find the pair of 1 and 2 such that it has the smallest manhattan distance. The matrix M has the following property:

1. For each row of M, there is at least one 1.
2. For each column of M, there is at least one 2.

For example

```
M = 0 1 0 2
    1 0 0 0
    0 2 2 1
    2 1 0 1
```

In this case, 
the 2 in the 3rd row, 2nd column and the 1 in the 4th row, 2nd column has manhattan distance = 1;
the 2 in the 4th row, 1st column and the 1 in the 4th row, 2nd column has manhattan distance = 1;
the 2 in the 3rd row, 3rd column and the 1 in the 3rd row, 4th column has manhattan distance = 1;

My question is: what is the quickest way to find pairs like these 3?

I have all the coordinates of these 1s and 2s. And I can do parallel computing, i.e., given an arbitrary 1 entry in matrix M, what is the quickest way to find the nearest 2 in manhattan distance?

Comment: breadth first search will give shortest distance to a 2 from a given 1.

Comment: If you have the coordinates of 1s and 2s, is finding all the pairwise distances not fast enough? Do you have some estimate of the maximum distance between the nearest 2 points?